# Vertical centering in Android

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, centering

I used flexbox, table and `vertical-align` to try to resolve it, but it doesn't have any effect.

You can see the screenshot below. Android's doesn't align middle (the `font-size` less than 12px) but iOS it work fine...

## Remove line-height

set `line-height: normal`, upper's spacing is less then bottom...

[image: remove line-height]

## Android

[image: android screenshot]

## iOS

[image: ios screenshot]

```css
.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 -5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.tag {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  min-width: 0;
}
.tag .caption {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #82879b;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.tag .caption:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border: 1px solid #82879b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h2> English </h2>

<div class="tags">
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">You</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">see</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">it's</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">in android</span></div>
</div>

<h2> Chinese </h2>

<div class="tags">
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">中</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">文</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">对</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">齐</span></div>
</div>

<h2> Japanese </h2>

<div class="tags">
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">エネルギッシュな</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">サニー</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">ハロー</span></div>
   <div class="tag"><span class="caption">ばか</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uLacb3zp/ ?

Comment: @pol the text `font-size` should be less than 12px, like 9px, and it will not center again... It make me so confuse...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can center the text in Android, and everywhere else, with much less code.

Here's a simplified version:

```css
.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.tag {
  flex: 0 0 23%;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.tag .caption {
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <div class="tag"><span class="caption">this</span></div>
  <div class="tag"><span class="caption">should</span></div>
  <div class="tag"><span class="caption">be centered</span></div>
  <div class="tag"><span class="caption">in android</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi~ when set the `font-size` less than 12px, the text position doesn't center (vertical, not horizontal) again...

Comment: I tested my answer in Android browsers. Text is centered perfectly both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: hmmmm... at last, I used `padding` to make it look centering... your solution is work fine in English, but in CJK(Chinese、Japan、Korean) it upper again, thanks, dude~

Comment: I'm trying this on Android just now. Nexus 6P. It is almost centered vertically, but still noticeably off towards the top. On PC it's perfect. UTF-8, no special characters.

Comment: Just tried on iPhone 5 - same thing. Padding doesn't help. Can make it look good on phone, but then messed up on PC.

Comment: @newbie
Please try: "line-height: normal;"